# Can a human be killed by electro-static discharge while performing daily chores?

Tags: electrostatics

During freezing-winter seasons, as soon as I reach my office and get off the warm-clothing; I get an electrostatic discharge whenever I touch a metallic water-fountain in my lab. The shock I get is sometimes so severe that for half-an hour my arm remain numb.

I am curious, whether is it possible that a human be killed from such an electro-static discharge while performing daily chores?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the biological response to an applied electric charge and not physics. Perhaps Biology.SE might be suitable?

Comment: I am looking for some physicist's response.

Comment: Your query is on the fatality of electric shock, this is outside the realm of physics.

Comment: A typical estimate for the capacitance of the human body is 100-200pF. Electrostatic discharge voltages range from a couple thousand to maybe 15kV. If you calculate the total energy in such a discharge, you end up with maybe 25mJ. That's far too little to kill a human (especially since almost all of the discharge current will flow trough layers of tissue close to the skin), however, it may provoke a panic reaction that could turn deadly under highly unfortunate circumstances e.g. if it happens on the steps of a ladder and the person falls.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electrical safety and the biological effects of electric discharge through the human body.

Answer (score 1):

Your body is a detector of electric current, in what you describe. Static electricity coming from clothes should not have such high current levels. Check   with a voltmeter, it is safer . I suspect that even those small screw drivers for checking live wires will light up. There must be  a leakage.

Comment: I probably didn't clear much in my question.
The water fountain is not electric at all, and after getting a shock, everything gets normal so is the fountain. However, fountain has a complete metallic body which might/must be earthed. I am sure that I get shock because fountain is very nicely earthed (0.7 $\Omega $).

Comment: what you describe is way out of what power  a spark from triboelectric effect can deliver,unless you are wearing unusual clothing, Of course there exist triboelectric generators.

Comment: triboelectric effect is really worth knowing. I suspect that it may be the possible cause. thanks